# Битрикс - Удаление всех товаров из корзины

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет! 
Нужно сделать кнопку "Удалить все" для корзины [bitrix:sale.basket.basket](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/store/sale/components_2/basket/sale_basket_basket.php). 
Удаление одной позиции в корзине делаю так

```
basket/?action=delete&id=654
```

А как все позиции удалить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще как бы так: скопировать шаблон компонента через эримтаж в свой шаблон для сайта. Потом в папке с **скопированныи шаблоном компонента** создать **result_modifier.php** ну и там написать такое:

```
<?
    if ($_POST["BasketDelete"] and CModule::IncludeModule("sale"))
    {
       CSaleBasket::DeleteAll(CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID());
    }
    ?>
```

И самое важное далее получается обращаемся к компоненту так: /ваш_путь?BasketDelete=Y вообще типа что там будет после равно в моем случаи не важно но можете проверку привести к лучшему виду к примеру ($_POST["BasketDelete"]=='Y') and ...

Answer (score 0):

В component_epilog:

```
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;

$request = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getInstance()->getContext()->getRequest();

if ($request->get('clear') !== null && Loader::includeModule("sale")) {
    CSaleBasket::DeleteAll(CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID());

    $redirect = $APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam('', ['clear']);

    LocalRedirect($redirect);
}
```

html:

```
<?php
use Bitrix\Main\Localization\Loc;?>

<a href="<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam('clear')?>" class="clear_basket"><?=Loc::getMessage('SALE_CLEAR_BASKET');?></a>
```

Ну, и js если кому-то это нужно (не вижу смысла вешать ajax на акшн очистки корзины)

```
// не самое красивое решение, т.к. не используется js-core битры, а значит возможны проблемы с script.js в sale.basket.basket, 
// но после очистки корзины эта страница станет бесполезной до тех пор, пока не появятся новые товары в корзине, так что /и так сойдёт/
$(function(){
   $('.clear_basket').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
      if(lnk){
            $.get(lnk, function(data){
                $('#basket_form').html( $(data).find('#basket_form').html() );
            });
        }
   });
});
```